# Site Column as an SSRS Dataset

Tags: 2010, reporting-services

Is it possible to use a Site Column (Choice) type as a dataset for use in SSRS reports?

I can use a combination of hidden parameters, VBA code and a list to effectively obtain a distinct list of values, which is close to what I want. It's expensive in terms of speed and operation to iterate through thousands of rows though.

Ideally, I'd like a sustainable way of getting at the Site Column choice values and using that to populate the SSRS parameter, in order to filter on it.

I can only use SSRS 2012, SharePoint Server 2010 (not ent) and the VBA code in SSRS, no C# or deplyable code allowed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can the VBA code access SharePoint Web Services?

Comment: Not sure, worth a look though - thanks. I'll report back.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a straight forward way to take the values from a Choice column other than the method you likely already tried.  An alternative would be to create a new list that stores the values and then add that list as a Dataset, then use that dataset as the parameter.